# variable me carga undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una variable de sesión `user?.id` que solo carga después de haber cargado el proyecto, quiere decir que la primera vez que carga se muestra como `undefined` y ya después de volver a cargar el proyecto hay si me carga con el valor correspondiente pero me esta causando un error en mi GET en axios por que al cargar la primera vez me lo detecta como undefined y eso hace que se desencadene una serie de errores y no me carga mi `GET` , he intentado solucionar pero no lo he logrado conseguir.

```javascript
    import React, {useContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
    import {MyContext} from '../../login/MyContext'

    import axios from 'axios';

    function Perfil() {

        const {user} = useContext(MyContext); 
      
      const [data, setData]=useState([]);
        
     
        const peticionGet =async() =>{
                   
            await axios.get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/perfil_img/index.php?id_p=${user?.id}`) //ME CARGA UNDEFINED "user?.id"
            .then(response=>{
             setData(response.data);
            }).catch(error=>{
              console.log(error);
            })
        
          }


      useEffect(()=>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => {  
           
           peticionGet();
           
         }, 2000);
       return () => setInterval(interval); 
       },[])

         
      
    if(user)
        {
      return (
     
    <div>
    {console.log("AQUI CARGA LA VARIBLE SIN PROBLEMAS " + user?.id)}
    </div>

    </div>
       
      )
    }

    else if(!user){
        return"";
    }

    }

    export default Perfil
```

Comment: Cuando dices `y ya después de volver a cargar el proyecto hay si me carga` ¿Como se vuelve a cargar el proyecto? porque asi como esta parece que ese `useEffect` solo se ejecuta una vez

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré la solución:

1.Compruebe si `user.id` está configurado en `useEffect`. Si no, regresa.

2. Agregue el `user` objeto a la matriz de dependencia de `useEffect` para volver a activar, cada vez que `user` cambie.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!user?.id) return
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        peticionGet();

    }, 2000);
    return () => setInterval(interval);
}, [user])
```